# What is the solution of $\frac ax = \frac b{c-x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the solution of $\frac ax = \frac b{c-x}$ ?

there are at least two $x$ values that solves this equation, but using normal solving methods we can only arrive at $1$ solution for $x$. Why is that?

Comment: This is pretty unclear until you explain what you mean by "normal solving method".

Comment: $$\frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{c-x}\iff a(c-x)=bx\qquad x\neq 0,c$$
so we get a linear equation which has at most one solution. How are you getting two solutions for this equation?

Comment: Why do you say there are at least two x that solve the equation?

Comment: @Dave It can have infinitely many solutions if $c=0$ and $b=-a$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac {a}{x} = \frac {b}{c-x}$$

$x=0$ and $x=c$ are not solutions because dividing by zero is not defined.

Otherwise,

$$ a(c-x)=bx$$

$$ac-ax=bx$$

$$(a+b)x=ac$$

If $a+b=0$ and $ac=0$ then $x$ could be any real number.

If $a+b=0$ and $ac \ne 0$ then there is no solution.

Otherwise,

$$x=\frac {ac}{a+b}$$

Comment: If $x=0$ or $x=c$ then division by $0$ makes the equation problematic.